# Is there an easy way to make sessions timeout in flask?

Tags: python, session, timeout, flask

I'm building a website with flask where users have accounts and are able to login.
I'm using flask-principal for the loging in part and the role management.
Is there a way of making the user's session expire after say 5 minutes or 10 minutes?
I was not able to find that in flask documentation or, flask-principal's documentation.

I thought of a way of doing it by hand, set a variable server-side with a time tag at the moment of login and at the next action the user takes, the server verifies the time-delta on that timestamp and deletes the session.

Comment: Do you want expire user session after inactivity of 5 or 10 minutes or  simply expire irrespective of activity level?

Comment: for inactivity i will have to implement that. just to expire when the browser is closed, or 24 hours. It does not expire at all right now.

Comment: To make a session expire relative to activity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760486/resetting-the-expiration-time-for-a-cookie-in-flask

Answer (score 161, accepted):

flask sessions expire once you close the browser unless you have a permanent session. You can possibly try the following:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from flask import session, app

@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=5)
```

By default in Flask, permanent_session_lifetime is set to 31 days.

Comment: I believe it is also true that your session will be reset if you change your `app.secret_key` and restart the server.

Comment: session.permanent is False by default: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.session.permanent

Comment: Do you know what gets called when the permanent_session_lifetime expires?

Comment: So only if I use session.permanent = True I have to explictly expire it when I want to. right?

Comment: To expire the session after a timedelta relative to the last request please see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19795394/227884. @codegeek: Can you please update your answer with the link. Would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason of using `before_request` here instead of `before_first_request`?

Comment: @srctaha I think maybe he want to refresh the expires every time people visit site

Comment: This is working perfectly! Any suggestion on how we can flash a message when the session expires?

Comment: how would we find out that a user is kicked out due to session timeout?

Comment: why is this session.permanent called permanent if the goal is to not make it permanent?

Comment: By doing this way, it's impossible to implement expiration for each request. For example, if user choose to remember me, if we want `permanent_session_lifetime` will persist for 30 days, if not, it's only 5 minutes.

Comment: @dganesh2002 Have you find a way to interact with the session timeout? I need a way to flash a message or reroute the user after the session expires.

Comment: What should I do if a request is sent every second to refresh the session? I have tried setting ```app.config['SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST'] = False``` and the session still gets refreshed.

Comment: @srctaha I believe that `before_request` is necessary to make it work for different clients. `before_first_request` only runs for the first request of the first client to this instance of the server.

Answer (score 63):

Yes, We should set

```
session.permanent = True
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=5)
```

But I don't think it should be set at `app.before_request`, This will lead to set them too may times.

The `permanent_session_lifetime` is a [Basics Configuration](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/#configuration-basics), so it should be set at you configure the app:

```
 from datetime import timedelta
 app = Flask(__name__)
 app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'xxxxxxxxx'
 app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] =  timedelta(minutes=5)
```

The `session` will created for each client, seperated from other clients. So, I think the best place to set `session.permanent` is when you `login()`:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    #After Verify the validity of username and password
    session.permanent = True
```

Comment: For Apache-Airflow (which uses Flask) setting this in https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/auth/backends/ldap_auth.py did not work for me.

Comment: Update the link in the answer to the latest version: [Basics Configuration](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME)

Comment: I use flask session with rooms and broadcasting etc. above solution however did not work for me. I would expect that after 5min the user is directly logged out and redirected to login page .... is this possible with permanent session? or Do I have to achieve this using db and storing the login date?

Comment: Is it possible to set session lifetime per each session? Eg. I have different user types and I want admin users to have a session valid for 1 hour, and the rest for 24 hours.

Answer (score 4):

Using a slight modification on CodeGeek's answer, the decorator **@before_first_request** is enough to get flask to "remember" the session timeout.  **@before_request** runs before EACH request, which is not necessary. I've tested this with different timeouts and it works.

The calls are explained [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/).

```
from datetime import timedelta
from flask import session, app

@app.before_first_request  # runs before FIRST request (only once)
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=5)
```