# Resetting the expiration time for a cookie in Flask

Tags: python, session, flask

I'm using the the Python web framework Flask.  I use sessions in my app.  For my app called `main`, I've got the setting `main.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(days=5)`, so that a user will remain logged in for 5 days after logging in.  But even an active user will be logged out after 5 days.  I would like the expiration time to reset each time they visit the site, so you get logged out only after 5 days of **inactivity**.  Most sites work this way.  How do I do that with Flask?

Comment: Flask tries to give you the tools to write something like this yourself. How you define "activity" is website dependent. Is "activity" visiting the site, or something like purchasing a product? As you can see, there couldn't be an option such as "inactivity", you would have to implement it yourself.

Comment: For my case, activity just means visiting the site.  If they visit any page on the site before the cookie expires, I would like the expiration to be reset to 5 days from that time.

Comment: Look at this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/49891626](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49891626) It works for me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can renew the session to the client at each request using a `@before_request` handler.

Try the following:

```
@app.before_request
def func():
  session.modified = True
```

Comment: Works beautifully.  I've actually wanted the `@app.before_request` feature for other reasons previously, so this is great to know about.

Comment: This doesn't work while using server side sessions (flask-kvsession). Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @zengr this is a problem of flask-kvsession as it says to be "a drop-in replacement for Flask‘s signed cookie-based session management". It doesn't do its work completely. Post a bug report. One workaround may be to call the `.regenerate()` method.

Comment: Yeah, I dumped flask-kvsession and implemented this instead: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/75/

Answer (score 5):

Should be enough with:

```
from datetime import timedelta

# User will be logout after this time of inactivity
PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = timedelta(minutes=30)
SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST = True
```

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/

Comment: No need to set 'SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST ' as True because its by default set as True.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get cookie token from `request`

```
    auth_token = request.cookies.get('jwt')
```

2. Set token back in response cookie with `max_age`. As a result, `max_age` moves forward with each request activity. If there is no activity from the user side then cookie will expire on time.

   ```
    response.set_cookie(key="jwt",
                       value=auth_token,
                       max_age=IN_SECONDS,
                       httponly=True,
                       samesite="Strict",
                       )
   ```

**I did it for myself as follows:**

I already had a token_rquired_decorator on each API call. So I placed my logic there in the `make_response` function.

```
def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):

        # some_code here 
        _response, status_code = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return make_response(_response, auth_token, status_code)

    return decorated
```

In `make_response` function.  I am setting a cookie again that will eventually move my cookie expiry time forward with each request considering as activity.

```
 def make_response(_response: Dict[str, Any], auth_token: str, status_code: int):
    response = Response(
        json.dumps(_response).encode('utf-8'),
        status=status_code,
        mimetype="application/json"
    )
    response.set_cookie(key="jwt",
                        value=auth_token,
                        max_age=Config.COOKIE_MAX_AGE,
                        httponly=True,
                        samesite="Strict",
                        )
    return response
```

I hope it will help the community. Don't forget to appreciate it. thanks