# Logout if session expires from no activity and redirect to login page

Tags: python, redirect, flask, logout, expired-sessions

I'm trying to update a website with flask where users have accounts and are able to login. I want to make user session expire and logout if there is no activity for more than 10 mins and redirect the user to the login page.

I want to update it in `@app.before_request` and below is my code. How do I check for the login time and check if there has been no activity, then logout.

```
@app.before_request
def look_for_user(user=None):
        g.usr = {}
    g.api = False
    if user:
        g.usr = user
    if 'user_id' in session:
        g.usr = get_user((session['user_id'])) //from db
        if not g.usr:
            g.usr = {}
    if not g.usr:
        if request.url_rule:
            if request.url_rule.rule not in app.config['LOGIN_NOT_REQUIRED']:
                session['postlogin_landing_page'] = request.path
                if g.api:
                    return jsonify(error=True, error_message='Invalid Login/Token')
                else:
                    return redirect(app.config['LOGIN_URL'])
    elif 'login_page' in session and request.url_rule:
        if request.url_rule.rule not in app.config:
            landing_page = session.pop('login_page')
            return redirect(landing_page)
```

Comment: Could you use the cookie module?  Perhaps each page load could check the stored cookie and, if it's still valid, set a new one with an expiration of 10 minutes.  Otherwise, instead of continuing with the page load, it would log out and redirect to the login page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `permanent_session_lifetime` and the `session.modified` flag as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760486/resetting-the-expiration-time-for-a-cookie-in-flask/19795394).

Note that sessions are not permanent by default, and need to be activated with `session.permanent = True`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11785722/246534).

Comment: im trying the same setting app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=2) , but its not happening. ? 

Not sure where I'm going wrong. Do I need to set permanent session time somewhere. And then use session.modified ?

Comment: as suggested in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783025/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-sessions-timeout-in-flask/11785722#11785722 )
Changed and added :

      @app.before_request
       def make_session_permanent():
             session.permanent = True
            app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=5)
             session.modified = True

After adding I'm not able to login, it keeps redirecting to login page .

Answer (score 1):

solution of your problem and for that you have to import datetime.timedelta library

```
session.permanent = True
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(seconds=3)
session.modified = True
```