# Flask permanent session: where to define them?

Tags: python, session, cookies, flask, flask-login

By default, Flask uses volatile sessions, which means the session cookie is set to expire when browser closes.   In order to use permanent sessions, which will use a cookie with a defined expiration date, one should set `session.permanent = True`, as is [mentioned in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783025/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-sessions-timeout-in-flask), and the expiration date will be set based on `config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME']`.

I am surprised that session lifetime is defined in config file, yet it is not possible to request the use of permanent sessions through configuration, such as a `config['USE_PERMANENT_SESSION'] = True`.   But so be it.

My question is: if you *do* want permanent sessions, what is the best place to define them ?   Is it in an `@app.before_request` function as proposed in mentioned question ?   But that would mean setting it over again at each request ?   It seems that once set, `session.permanent` remains true till end of session.

Permanent sessions are generally used *after sign-in*, so maybe the best place to request them is while processing `login_user()` ?     So is the best policy to  use volatile session cookies for all anonymous pages, and switch to permanent sessions by doing a `session.permanent = True` at sign-in ?

And one might want to set a different lifetime depending on whether it is the ordinary `session` cookie, or the `remember_me` cookie.   What would be the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm surprised no on has answered this question. It seems like there should be some type of config variable `SESSION_PERMANENT = True`. But unfortunately there isn't. As you mentioned this is the best way to do it.

```
@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True
```

Comment: is config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] value in seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: @dashesy, you're referring to a configuration in the [Flask-Session](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/) extension. In vanilla Flask session management, `config['SESSION_PERMANENT']` does not exist, not even in the master branch.

Comment: @RandomCOSMOS The value for `app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME']` is in seconds, as you can see in the docs: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/#PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME

Answer (score 11):

## Should you use `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME` and `session.permanent`?

What you actually want to do is probably expiring users' sign-in status. However, this configuration expires the session object/cookie which contains the users' sign-in status as well as (potentially) some other data that you stored in `session`.

## Do you need to set `session.permanent`?

According to [Flask's doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME):

> Flask’s default cookie implementation validates that the cryptographic signature is not older than this value.

`session.permanent` is an add-on of `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME`. Sometimes it is okay if you do not set `session.permanent` to True.

If you do not set `session.permanent`, the session cookie's lifetime will not be affected by `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME`. But Flask will look at `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME` and a timestamp in the session cookie, to see if the session cookie is still valid. If the timestamp is too older than specified by `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME`, it will be ignored. But the cookie still exists.

This is how Flask ignores session cookie:

```
def open_session(self, app, request):
    s = self.get_signing_serializer(app)
    if s is None:
        return None
    val = request.cookies.get(app.session_cookie_name)
    if not val:
        return self.session_class()
    max_age = total_seconds(app.permanent_session_lifetime)
    try:
        data = s.loads(val, max_age=max_age)
        return self.session_class(data)
    except BadSignature:
        return self.session_class()
```

If you set `session.permanent=True`, the validation will still be done. And what's more, the session cookie will expire and be deleted from the browser after `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME`.

This is how `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME` control the expiration of the cookie:

```
def get_expiration_time(self, app, session):
    if session.permanent:
        return datetime.utcnow() + app.permanent_session_lifetime


def save_session(self, app, session, response):
    ...
    expires = self.get_expiration_time(app, session)
    val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))
    response.set_cookie(
        app.session_cookie_name,
        val,
        expires=expires,
        httponly=httponly,
        domain=domain,
        path=path,
        secure=secure,
        samesite=samesite
    )
```

## Do you need to set `session.permanent` for every request?

`session.permanent` by default is actually `session['_permanent']`. Its value will stay in `session`.
But if you are going to assign it only when users sign in, keep alert by checking how users can by-pass the sign-in route to sign in. For example, by signing up.

Comment: Very detailed and helpful answer, could you elaborate a little bit how users can bypass the sign-in route by signing up?

Comment: @oeter suppose your service's user experience is designed to put users in a signed-in status once they sign up, so users do not need to sign in right after sign up. Then the sign-up logic in your service probably will have the logic granting the session, which may or may not be shared with the sign-in logic.

Answer (score 6):

I choose what you said "login_user()"

```
@asset.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    #After Verify the validity of username and password
    session.permanent = True
```

if it set at **app.before_request**, This will lead to set them too may times.

Comment: Have you considered that the `session['_permanent']` can be set to false or removed from the request made by the client? This would result in bypassing the validation of the expiration time.

Answer (score 0):

As @Hooloovoo13 indicated in his comment to Mikey's reply (with a dead link), you could use the [Flask-Session](https://flasksession.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) extension to get full control over your Flask sessions. It lets you configure the session-specific parameters when setting up the application:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_session import Session


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
Session(app)
```

Although the code above is actually pointless since the Flask-Session extension default value for `SESSION_PERMANENT` is `True`:

> SESSION_PERMANENT |
> Whether use permanent session or not, default to be True only  since the default value