# Why sessions cookies are not saved in browser?

Tags: angular, api, flask, session, cookies

I'm making a website with angular and I use Flask as my API.
Everything was ok until now, but I want to use session with flask, so I have to get the session cookie and send it back.

#### The problem is: Cookies are not saved on my browsers (Firefox/Google Chrome).

When I try with another tool like Insomnia/Postman, there is no problem! The cookie is saved and everything work when the cookie is sent back!

I have read a lot of same situation (I mean, with the domain parameter which need two dots), but even when I try:

> angular client -> dev.localhost.local

> Flask API -> api.localhost.local

> domain -> .localhost.local

[image: Get the set-cookie option]

> the browser get the set-cookie options

[image: no cookie saved]

> no cookie saved

[image: no session saved]

> no session saved

Browser just doesn't save my session...

I tried a lot of configuration:

Domain : `.localhost.local`, `localhost.local`,`dev.localhost.local`,`.dev.localhost.local`

I also tried to use different header to expose `set-cookie` and `cookie` header. I set the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to True.

Nothing is working, so if you have any idea, I take it.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to my mind is that a *session* cookie *should* be non-persistent and will only stay for one session. To make a cookie persistent-ish, you need to define a lifetime for the cookie, by either giving it a duration until expiry in seconds (max-age) or a specific date in the form of a UNIX timestamp. To read more [about cookie lifetimes see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#define_the_lifetime_of_a_cookie).

To do this with flask *session* cookies see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34118093/flask-permanent-session-where-to-define-them).

Otherwise, you can also use a [response with `response.set_cookie`](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/flask.Response.set_cookie.html):

```py
from flask import Flask, make_response, request
 
app = Flask(__name__)
 
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    # Do you authentication, authorization …
    resp = make_response("Session granted")
    # Set session cookie for a day
    resp.set_cookie('session', 'SESSION_KEY', max_age=60 * 60 * 24, domain='.localhost.local')
    return resp
```

Comment: I retried everything I did with a non-permanent cookie and I added a max-age, but browsers still dont save anything