# Does Flask-Login's `remember_me` override Flask's `permanent`?

Tags: flask, flask-login

[Remember-me](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#remember-me) is
a [parameter](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.login_user)

```
flask_login.login_user(user, remember=False, duration=None, force=False, fresh=True)
```

to `login_user` in `Flask-Login`. It makes it possible "to remember the user after their session expires."

And yet with just Flask (and not Flask-Login)

```
'PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(31)
```

is set by default to 31 days in the `default_config` (and it can be suitably modified).
Also `session.permanent` can be [set](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#sessions) to make a session permanent,
[perhaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11785722/704972) through:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from flask import session, app

@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=5)
```

Does Flask-Login's `remember_me` override Flask's `permanent`? How do they interact?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`remember_me` is not stored in the Flask session. It is is stored in a *separate* cookie who's name and expiration is [handled in the Flask-Login configuration](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cookie-settings):

> **`REMEMBER_COOKIE_NAME`**
>   The name of the cookie to store the “remember me” information in. **Default**: `remember_token`
>
> **`REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION`**
>   The amount of time before the cookie expires, as a `datetime.timedelta` object or integer seconds. **Default**: 365 days (1 non-leap Gregorian year)
>
> **`REMEMBER_COOKIE_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST`**
>   If set to `True` the cookie is refreshed on every request, which bumps the lifetime. Works like Flask’s `SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST`. **Default**: `False`

plus a few more `REMEMBER_COOKIE_*` settings to control visibility of the cookie (domain, path, encrypted connections only, and if code running in the browser can access the value).

The Flask session configuration has no bearing on this; that's a separate cookie with separate settings. The *remember me* functionality does not interact with Flask's `permanent_session_lifetime` / `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME` setting, the [Flask `SESSION_COOKIE_*` configuration](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#SESSION_COOKIE_NAME), or `app.session.permanent`, at all.

By default, Flask uses `session` as the session cookie name, and Flask-Login uses `remember_token` for the *remember me* cookie.