# Python Flask - how to remember anonymous users via cookie/session?

Tags: python, flask, session-cookies

I`m building a Flask web site that is a part of a research experiment.
I need to be able to remember anonymous users so every visitor to my web site will be anonymous and unique but also be remembered so they could not enter the web site again (they will get redirection to a "thank you for your participation" page).

How can I do it? I looked into flask.session (how to generate unique anonymous id and save it to user cookie?) and Flask-login (have to be with user login to get an id) but didn't find the specific solution for this problem.

please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no perfect solution to your problem because you will not be able to identify a user if they are anonymous.

The most practical is probably to use sessions and save that they completed the survey in a session variable. But if they clear their cookies they will be able to enter the site again.

Example implementation:

```
from flask import session, app

@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True
```

In your survey form view:

```
if not "already_participated" in session:
    ... Display form
```

And then in your submit view:

```
session["already_participated"] = True
```

Comment: hi, can you please write a small example of how to use the session in flask for this problem?

Comment: Here is some code. Don't forget to make sessions permanent so that they are not deleted when the user closes the browser. The default longevity for permanent sessions is 31 days. But you can change it if necessary (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783025/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-sessions-timeout-in-flask)